# How to follow redirections on a url and get content and headers in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What's the most efficient way to open a url, follow any redirections, and get the html content and also the url headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing this from inside a rails application because of the tags you specified. The solution isn't trivial, but here's a good walkthrough: [Rails Tips Walkthrough](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/03/04/following-redirects-with-nethttp/)